I tried to update from 22.04 lts to 24.04 lts
My laptop is a little old and I tried to update from 22.04 to 24.04 after the cmd gathered everything and unpacked everything it's a blank screen now and it's been over an hour and I don't know what to do, help please

24.04 is still in beta. It hasn't been released yet.

Be patient. 24.04 is in the process of being released today. No need to hurry.

How did you update ? What command did you use ?
